# I want to see the real image, not an icon

Tags: ruby, image, carrierwave

I only see an icon, and not the real image (also on the index page).

[image: I can see only icon not a real image (also in index page)]

```
제목:<%= @food.title %> <br> <br>

<img src="<%= @food.image %>"><br> <br>

내용:<%= @food.content %> <br> <br>

<form action="/food/edit/<%= @food.id %>"> <input type="submit" value="수정"></form> 
<form action="/food/destroy/<%= @food.id %>"> <input type="submit" value="삭제"></form>
```

I don't understand how an image can be saved in the database. I found a method that saves a url, but I upload the image file usually. I made an input tag that has the file type. How can I save the image? I have installed carrierwave.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `Food` model looks like, but try this (since you are using CarrierWave, add `.url`):

```
<img src="<%= @food.image.url %>"><br> <br>
```

or:

```
<%= image_tag @food.image.url %>
```

The icon you are seeing is the default icon shown by the browser if the image path is not found.

Reference: [CarrierWave ActiveRecord](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#activerecord)

Answer (score 0):

What is `@food.image`? Is it a url, or the image itself? If it is a url, `<img src="<%= @food.image %>">` should work. If it is the image itself, perhaps uploaded by carrierwave, you should use `<%= image_tag(@food.image) %>`.

Comment: OP is already doing `<img src="<%= @food.image %>">` and it is not working.